# Can a wizard with the Artificer Initiate feat upcast a Cure Wounds spell that they learn using the feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, spellcasting, spell-slots

The description of the [Artificer Initiate](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/artificer-initiate) feat states, in part (TCoE, p. 79):

> You’ve learned some of an artificer’s inventiveness:
>
> - You learn one cantrip of your choice from the artificer spell list,
>   and you learn one 1st-level spell of your choice from that list.
>   Intelligence is your spellcasting ability for these spells.
> - You can cast this feat's 1st-level spell without a spell slot, and you must
>   finish a long rest before you can cast it in this way again.
>   **You can also cast the spell using any spell slots you have**.

Can a wizard with the Artificer Initiate feat upcast a *Cure Wounds* spell that they learn using the feat?

So, in my last session, one player casts a *Cure Wounds* using a 5th-level spell slot, and he expected to cure 5d8+5 hit points. My understanding is that he can use a high-level spell slot, but the spell is always cast in level 1 (like the *shield* spell) since he is an artificer **initiate**. Am I wrong, by RAW?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Yes, you can gain the benefit of using a higher-level spell slot to cast a *cure wounds* spell that you learned from the feat

The text of [*cure wounds*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/cure-wounds) says:

> ***At Higher Levels.*** When you cast this spell using a spell slot of 2nd level or higher, the healing increases by 1d8 for each slot level above 1st.

Using a higher-level spell slot fits this condition; therefore, the extra healing applies.

See also the rule on [casting a spell at a higher level](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#CastingaSpellataHigherLevel) (*PHB*, p. 201):

> When a spellcaster casts a spell using a slot that is of a higher level than the spell, the spell **assumes the higher level for that casting**. For instance, if Umara casts *magic missile* using one of her 2nd-level slots, that *magic missile* is 2nd level.
>
> Effectively, the spell expands to fill the slot it is put into.
>
> Some spells, such as *magic missile* and *cure wounds*, have more powerful effects when cast at a higher level, as detailed in a spell's description.